# disconnect dojo event of datetimebox

Tags: dojo

I wanted to disconnect event of datetimebox (_onBlur). It is mentioned in the file "TextBox.js". 'dojo.disconnect' works on custom events that I define in my javascript. But i want to do the same for the dojo widget itself. I cannot disconnect events declared (_onBlur) in the dojo widget(Textbox.js).

Below is declaration in the Textbox.js widget.. how should i declare disconnect event that below event is never call ???.. again below code is from widget & it is not my code.. using dojo.disconnect i am able to disconnect events declared in my custom js file but I m not able to disconnect events such as below declared in widget js file that comes with dojo library.. please suggest

_onBlur: function(e){

```
        this._setBlurValue();
```

this.inherited(arguments);

```
        if(this._selectOnClickHandle){
            this.disconnect(this._selectOnClickHandle);
        }
        if(this.selectOnClick && dojo.isMoz){
            this.textbox.selectionStart = this.textbox.selectionEnd = undefined; // clear selection so that the next mouse click doesn't reselect
        }

        this._updatePlaceHolder();

},
```

---

Simon, I want it because it is advantageous to have it when we want to override dojo inbuilt events with our own custom events. Example is when you use dojo grid and use arrow key (up, right, down..) the cell is highlighted (dotted line is surrounding the cell) indicating current cell ... now if you want to disable i.e keep the cell hghlighted for a while lets say you display edit/text on that cell you but if user again tries to press arrow key you will see the dotted line is still rotating around which you do not want... easiest is to disable/disconnect the event in this case event tied to grid is "doKeyEvent" which listens to key event and does the hghlgt of cell.. I have achieved this by keypress & other events to counteract or nullify what grid is doing but still.. easiest is to disable/disconnect this grid events itself & let concentrate on  business events & logic reqd rather than try to code for events that are default to the dojo component which might be good for some business not for all .. this counter events has to be taken place for other components as well

Answer (score 0):

Dojo disconnect will only work with events added by dojo.connect. I don't think you can do what it is ur trying to do. Why do u need to do this perhaps there's another way around ur issue?

Answer (score 0):

As Simon pointed out Dojo disconnect will only work with events added by dojo.connect.

But a solution to your problem could be to override the `onBlur()` function so it will not execute, example:

```
this.onBlur = function(){
    return false;
}
```